# Infinite Scrolling Text in 2 rows

Tags: javascript, html, css, marquee

I am building a scrolling text RSS feed based on this solution:
https://ryanmulligan.dev/blog/css-marquee/

But the text should be duplicated into a second row. In the second row the text should enter the viewport on the right side when text exits the left side of the first row.

I have tried to place a 100vw (or 100%) left padding on the second row, but it breaks the logic of the continuous loop.

Here is the example: https://codepen.io/hexagoncircle/pen/eYMrGwW

Does anyone have an idea how to create infinite scrolling text within 2 rows based on the CodePen example?

```
    <div>
    <div class="marquee">
        <div class="marquee__content"></div>

        <div aria-hidden="true" class="marquee__content"></div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="marquee2">
        <!-- <div class="empty-div"></div> -->
        <div class="marquee__content2"></div>

        <div aria-hidden="true" class="marquee__content2"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
@keyframes scroll {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(calc(-100% - var(--gap)));
  }
}

@keyframes scroll2 {
  from {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(calc(-100% - var(--gap2)));
  }
}

.marquee {
  --gap: 0.1rem;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  user-select: none;
  gap: var(--gap);
}

.marquee__content {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  gap: var(--gap);
}

.marquee__content {
  animation: scroll 15s linear infinite;
}

.marquee__content > * {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.marquee2 {
  --gap2: 0.1rem;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  user-select: none;
  gap: var(--gap2);
}

.marquee__content2 {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  gap: var(--gap2);
}

.marquee__content2 {
  animation: scroll2 15s linear infinite;
}

.marquee__content2 > * {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: system-ui, sans-serif;
    font-size: 25vh;
}

img {
    transform: scale(1.6) translate(0, 10%);
    height: 25vh;
}
```